# R aggregate data.frame with date column

Tags: r, object, aggregate, as.date

I have the data frame resambling the one in the below

```
Date       Expenditure Indicator
29-01-2011 5455        212
25-01-2012 5452        111
11-02-2011 365         5
```

I'm currently interested in summing up the *Expenditure* values, I'm trying to use the function below

```
dta.sum <- aggregate(x = dta, FUN = sum, 
                         by = list(Group.date = dta$date))
```

but R returns the following error, **Error in Summary.Date(c(15614L, 15614L, 15614L, 15614L, 15614L, 15614L,  : sum not defined for "Date" objects**. The *Date* column was previously defined as date with use of the *as.Date* function. Analogous function but with the *mean* works fine.

```
dta.sum <- aggregate(x = dta, FUN = mean 
                             by = list(Group.date = dta$date))
```

I would like to keep date formatted as date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indicate the variables you are trying to get the aggregate of in your aggregate statement, and this problem should be resolved:

```
dta.sum <- aggregate(x = dta[c("Expenditure","Indicator")],
                     FUN = sum,
                     by = list(Group.date = dta$Date))
```

EDITED TO ADD EXPLANATION: When you give the `aggregate` argument as just `dta`, aggregate attempts to apply the argument to every column. `sum` is not defined for date values in R, and therefore you are getting errors. You want to exclude the grouping column by using the code described above.

Comment: Thank you very much it seems that it's working. Just to add to the discussion, can I also make the old date column disappear in the same function without doing **list(date = dta$date)**? I like to keep functions neat and concise and it produces a table with Group.date and date column, one being redundant. I would like the aggregate function to drop the redundant date column automatically, if possible.

Comment: I think you need to do the `list()` but that you might be able to get away without naming the list elements (i.e without Group.date).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 5):

Or use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dta %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Tot.Expenditure = sum(Expenditure))
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade from base and use `data.table` instead to simplify (and speed up) your code/life:

```
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(dta)

dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Date]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df <- data.frame(c('29-01-2011', '25-01-2012', '11-02-2011'), c(5455, 5452, 365), c(212, 211, 5))
colnames(df) <- c('Date', 'Expenditure', 'Indicator')
colSums(df[2])

#>Expenditure 
#11272
```