# Grouping Data by POSIXlt in R

Tags: r, posix

I want to group data by date-time / POSIXlt.

I have a data frame which has date-time variable. So I have converted into POSIXlt:

```
         datetime                value            POSIXlt
1 2015-06-21 21:40:56.934875000    36       2015-06-21 21:40
2 2015-06-21 21:40:57.963022000    35       2015-06-21 21:40
3 2015-06-21 21:40:58.394573000    30       2015-06-21 21:40
4 2015-06-21 21:40:59.349857000    31       2015-06-21 21:40
5 2015-06-21 21:50:56.963022000    11       2015-06-21 21:50
6 2015-06-21 21:50:58.127052000    33       2015-06-21 21:50
```

And I want output something like this:

```
    time            sum(value)
2015-06-21 21:40        132
2015-06-21 21:50        44
```

Comment: What is the format of your data.frame? What is the desired output? What do you mean by grouping?

Comment: @Pascal: Sorry for the unclear question. Now I added update...

Comment: possible duplicate of [R aggregate data.frame with date column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788450/r-aggregate-data-frame-with-date-column)

Comment: `POSIXlt` doesn't play nice with `aggregate` usually - try: `aggregate(dat["value"],list(time=as.POSIXct(trunc(as.POSIXlt(dat$datetime), units="mins"))),FUN=sum)`

Comment: @thelatemail Oops, didn't saw your comment

Comment: @Pascal: I'm was able to aggregate by date. But that doesn't solve my problem. So asked this question...

Comment: You can post the answer yourself, giving credit to @thelatemail .