# sum not definted for "Date" objects aggregate error

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has columns date and volume.

Trying to sum up the volumes by date i used:

```
volume_per_month <- aggregate(x ,by = list(x$date), FUN = sum)
```

I get :

Error in Summary.Date(c(14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 14610,  : 
  sum not defined for "Date" objects

Any ideas? I ran this before without problems but used this recently :

```
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); 
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

not sure if relate.d

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R aggregate data.frame with date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788450/r-aggregate-data-frame-with-date-column)

Comment: You are supplying the wrong input: `aggregate(x$volume,by = list(x$date), FUN = sum)`. See the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening,

It looks like it's trying to sum the date column. I haven't used aggregate in a long time, but this worked for me:

```
x <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date(), v1 = rnorm(5), v2 = runif(5))
aggregate(x[, setdiff(names(x), "date")] , by = list(x$date), FUN = sum)
```

Best,
Jonny